# 2d numpy array sum excluding one index location

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate sum of 2D numpy array but excluding one index location, such as the array:

```
array([[0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 8., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

will result 12 when I want to exclude the position of [2][1]. My for loop function works:

```
def num_order(arr):
    tot = 0
    for row in range(len(arr)):
        for col in range(len(arr)):
            if row != exclude_x or col != exclude_y:
                tot += base[row][col]
    return tot
```

but I need more concise way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quickest way would be just adding all of them and then substracting that specific value:

```py
def num_order(arr, exclude_x: int, exclude_y: int):
    return np.sum(arr) - arr[exclude_x, exclude_y]
```

Why this is much quicker? Many of the `numpy` methods are implemented in C and taking advantage of vectorization techniques. Therefore, everything you can do with these functions instead of iterating with python `for` loops will be much quicker

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just sum everything and then subtract the elements that you do not want

```py
np.sum(array) - array[row, col]
```